# Trouble publishing VS 2010 ASP.Net MVC 3 Razor web application to IIS 6/7

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis, razor, web

I have been trying to get my feet wet with MVC by building a simple CRUD web application linked to a SQL 2008 database. Everything works great when I run the project from within VS, but I have run into nothing but failure after failure trying to get the application to publish successfully using either IIS 6, or 7.

I have googled my fingers to the bone trying various fixes and methods for publishing, but so far have just been running into wall after wall. I feel like there must be something basic I am overlooking to get this going, but I am stumped.

I was hoping that someone with more experience working in this environment might be able to suggest some rookie mistakes I could be making, or any tips for publishing an MVC web app for the first time.

Thanks in advance,
Patrick Sean Henderson

Comment: Hi, we really need more information to help you out.  Are there specific errors or problems you are running into.  How are you trying to publish, etc. Give us as much as possible!

Comment: Sorry for the delay, other client projects popped up, so this went on the back burner for a bit. I will verify the assumptions you listed below, and post back with more error detail as soon as possible.

Answer (score 0):

We really need more information but making some assumptions here are things to verify:

**Assumptions:**

1. IIS 7.x
2. Proper .NET version installed
3. VS2010 & NuGet
4. File System Based Deployment

**Suggestions:**

1. Make sure you include the deployable assemblies required.

   - Right Click MVC project in VS
   - Select "Include Deployable Assemblies"
   - Check off the required assemblies
2. I'd have more with more background details

Post an update when you can!

Brent